# How do I control the brightness of a TFT LCD through SPI (No Backlight Pin)

Tags: led, esp32, lcd, c++, tft

I recently purchased a TFT LCD (GMT020-02 VER1.1)

The screen uses the ST7789V LED Driver and does not include a backlight control pin, So Originally I though that it was impossible to control it (i.e shorted to VCC) but the manufacturer assured me that it was possible. And then proceeded to ghost me.

I'm using Bodmer's "TFT_eSPI" and an ESP32 (Arduino Framework C++) and have tried several things like:

```
tft.writecommand(0x53);
tft.writedata(0x38);
tft.writecommand(0x51);
tft.writedata(0x00);
```

All to no avail unfortunately.

So my question is, how do I control the brightness of the screen through SPI?
and If it's impossible, could I physically expose some pcb trace and use it to control the backlight?

I think that's all but I always forget something so apologies if I did. Thanks in advance!